# Cypress Testing: stuck at wait-on http://localhost:3000

Tags: reactjs, cypress, circleci

I am running cypress with circleci

```
workflows:
  version: 2.1
  test_and_release:
    jobs:
      - cypress/run:
          working_directory: cats-client
          start: npm start
          wait-on: 'http://localhost:3000'
          filters:
            tags:
              only: /v?\d+\.\d+(\.\d+)?/
            branches:
              only: /.*/
```

but it suck **wait-on** on command

```
====>> Persisting to Workspace (skipped)
Warning: skipping this step: Missing workflow workspace identifiers, this step must be run in the context of a workflow
====>> Start
  #!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
npm start
====>> Wait-on http://localhost:3000
  #!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
npx wait-on http://localhost:3000
npx: installed 13 in 3.256s
Error: 
Too long with no output (exceeded 10m0s): context deadline exceeded

Step timedout
Error: runner failed (exited with 101)
Task failed
Error: task failed
```

My tries to fix that issue downgrade `react-scripts` --> 3.4.0

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8688#issuecomment-602678446

but still the same issue

Comment: What do you get when you run `npm start` locally ?

Comment: its working just fine and when I am trying that command locally npm start & node_modules/.bin/cypress run its working

Comment: Can you try locally `npm start  & wait-on http://localhost:3000 && node_modules/.bin/cypress run` ?

Comment: yea this command works locally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue was related to react-scripts and it's fixed by an upgrade from `3.4.3` to `4.0.3`

```
npm install --save --save-exact react-scripts@4.0.3
```

ref: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md

you will need to remove `package-lock.json` + `node_modules` folder